# ClassName undefined for some child in iconCreateFunction

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm working in a Vue2 web application using Leaflet and marker-cluster
I have some issue with the iconCreateFunction option
Here is a part of my tempate :

```html
 <v-marker-cluster :options="{ iconCreateFunction: iconCreateClsPrg}">
          <l-marker ....> 
                <l-icon :class-name="programme.display ? 'custom-marker notDisplay' : 'custom-marker display'">
```

And here is a part of the iconCreateClsPrg method :

```js
iconCreateClsPrg (marker_cluster) {
        const childs = marker_cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
         childs.forEach(child => {
            const cssCluster = child.options.icon.options.className;
            if (cssCluster && cssCluster.includes(this.css_marker_selected_simple)) {
                nbSelected++;
            }
          }
             ...
}
```

My problem is that sometimes my cssCluster const is undefined for no reason. It's not a regular behavior and it happens only at some zoom levels (which are not always the same).
If someone has an idea, it would be a big help !

I tryied to refresh the map, to wait until undefined (but had some issu with async method), restart the method from scratch, use for instead of forEach, ... but nothing worked

Comment: Might be related to the unmounting/remounting of the vue components. Try filtering by returning inside the forEach early using something like `if (!child?.options?.icon){ return }` right before const cssCluster = {...}. Does the behavior of the app still works as expected?

Comment: Hello @posixpascal thanks for your answer. No, it doenst work as expected if I do this. I have to get nbSelected incremented to build my cluster properly. As I can't bypass this step and can't get the good value for css cluster, I really don't know what to do

Comment: Can you prepare a codepen of some sort? I'll take a look. Need to see the bigger picture and mess around it to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to wait until the icon is fully loaded using promises :

```js
iconCreateClsPrg (marker_cluster) {
            let nbSelected = 0;
            try {
                const childs = marker_cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
                const promises = [];
                childs.forEach(child => {
                    // create promise to wait for all child
                    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
                        // wait for 0ms to let the browser render the page asynchonously
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            const cssCluster = child.options.icon.options.className;
                            if (cssCluster && cssCluster.includes(this.css_marker_selected_simple)) {
                                nbSelected++;
                            }
                            resolve();
                        }, 0);
                    });
                    promises.push(promise);
                });
                // wait for all child to be processed before continue
                Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    // do the rest of my things
                    const divIcon = new L.DivIcon({
                        html: htmlContent,
                        className: css_cluster,
                        iconSize: [30 + childCount, 30 + childCount],
                    });

                    // Ensure the map updates the cluster icon after the promise has resolved
                    marker_cluster.setIcon(divIcon);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                // deal with the error
            }
            // Return a blank icon to start with
            return new L.DivIcon({
            });
        }
```